# Is this IIFE switch statement causing unnecessary overhead?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, ecmascript-6, iife

I like using `const` and I like `switch` statements.

*note: The following is just a simplified example. The code in each case is slightly more complex and the returned object is a JSX component.*

Consider this:

```
let retval // can't declare as const!
switch (value) {
  case 'a':
    retval = 'aa'
  break
  case 'b':
    retval = 'bb'
  break
  case 'c':
    retval = 'cc'
  break
  case 'd':
    retval = 'dd'
  break
  default:
    retval = 'xx'
}

// mistakenly by purpose change retval here..
retval = function nope(){ return null }
```

but I **DO** want to use my consts, compare to this:

```
const retval = (() => {
  switch (value) {
    case 'a':
      return 'aa'
    case 'b':
      return 'bb'
    case 'c':
      return 'cc'
    case 'd':
      return 'dd'
    default:
      return 'xe'
  }
})()

retval = null // nope you are safe here!, raises error
```

Is it causing unnecessary overhead? ...or will the engine get advantage of it?

Answer (score 2):

You could use an object with a default value instead of a switch statement.

```
const retval = {a: 'aa', b: 'bb', c: 'cc', d: 'dd'}[value] || 'xe';
```

or with function, which is just at the end executed

```js
var value = 'd';
const retval = ({a: () => 'aa', b: () => 'bb', c: () => 'cc'}[value] || (() => 'xe'))();
console.log(retval);
```

Comment: Anyway, this is a neat solution - in certain cases. But still, this means that everything is processed and stored in a memory, right? I am building some complex JSX components and returning those. I don't need to build all the components, just the right one. Using this approach would build them all first, right?

Comment: ít depends on the content. if is is a function, then only the wanted could be executed.

Comment: I am in fact using functions in those cases, so this approach is really really cool! Add please a note to your answer so I can give it +1. Anyway I would still like to hear a word on my two questions, this really interests me, including a difference between this approach and an ordinary `switch`, especially in terms of processing speed, effectivity and resources.